# Объявление пространств имен в c#?

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Почему в данном примере:

```
// Пространства имен.

using NamespaceA;
using NamespaceA.NamespaceB;
using NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC;

namespace NamespaceA
{
    namespace NamespaceB
    {
        namespace NamespaceC
        {
            class MyClassC { }
        }

        class MyClassB { }
    }

    class MyClassA { }
}

// В данном месте импорт недопустим.
// Импорт допустим или в теле namespace, или перед всеми другими пространствами имен.

//using NamespaceA;
//using NamespaceA.NamespaceB;
//using NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC;

namespace Namespaces
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MyClassA myA = new MyClassA();
            MyClassB myB = new MyClassB();
            MyClassC myC = new MyClassC();
        }
    }
}
```

Который демонстрирует правилло :

> // В данном месте импорт недопустим.
>
> // Импорт допустим или в теле namespace, или перед всеми другими
>   пространствами имен.

Так вот, у меня вопрос к  данному правилу. Ведь c# - это компилируемый язык а не интерпретируемый, а значит код не читается строчка за строчкой а строится синтаксическое дерево. И поэтому мне интересно не все ли равно где объявлять пространства имен?

Comment: я не понял что должен показывать приведенный пример кода

Comment: Ну типа если снять комментарии с импорта ПИ - после их объявления то будет ошибка

Comment: Все равно, поэтому логично запретить объявлять его где попало. Это позволит во-первых улучшить структуру программы, а во-вторых немного упростить разбор кода компилятором. Разбросанные по всей программы подключения не есть хорошо.

Comment: Это логично, что юсинги должны быть в начале. Либо в начале файла, либо в начале неймспейса. Все чудесно.

Comment: @AlexKrass , я частично согласен ,но почему тогда  можно объявлять namespase в других namespase - ведь это тоже своего рода "разброс подключений по всей программе". Если у меня допусти есть два namespase- a A и B которые я объявил в начале программы, а затем уже в каждом из них объявляю еще другие namespase-ы и это при том, что эти "другие " namespase- ы у меня уже все равно будет в таком случае возможность написать до их объявления в namespase-ах A и B? Т.е разбросанность все равно остается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, компилятору было бы несложно динамически обновлять список привязок имён. Причиной правила является то, чтобы упростить понимание для *нас*, программистов, то есть, *принцип наименьшего удивления*.

Смотрите. Пускай у нас в другом файле есть такие декларации:

```
namespace A
{
    static class X { static public void Print() { System.Console.WriteLine("I am A::X"); } }
}

namespace B
{
    static class X { static public void Print() { System.Console.WriteLine("I am B::X"); } }
}
```

Заведём чистый файл, и в него поместим такую вот программу:

```
namespace A.Z
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X.Print();
            Utility.Run();
        }
    }

    using B;

    class Utility
    {
        static public void Run()
        {
            X.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Что должен выдать этот код? Текущим компилятором он не компилируется из-за `using B;` в середине, но очевидно, что он должен выдать то же самое, что и таких два отдельных файла:

```
namespace A.Z
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X.Print();
            Utility.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace A.Z
{
    using B;

    class Utility
    {
        static public void Run()
        {
            X.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

То есть, у нас находящиеся рядом выражения `X.Print()` интерпретируются по-разному. На `using` в середине файла можно и не обратить внимания, особенно если файлы и подлиннее, так что те, кто читают код, будут в недоумении, почему `X.Print` действует по-разному в разных местах файла, несмотря на то, что внутри никаких объявлений для `X` нет.

Таким образом, как мне кажется, правило придумано для того, чтобы код вёл себя по возможности единообразно, и не провоцировал ошибки.

Comment: +1, а еще есть статический анализатор, который проверяет корректность кода по мере его набора, его конечно можно научить таким трюкам, но ценой еще большего замедления IDE, которая и так не отличается слишком высокой скоростью из-за использования рефлексии для intellisense

Comment: т.е как я понял это сделано что бы что using гдето дальше по коду не влияло  на предыдущий код, когда  ?(когда компилятор будет проходится по дереву - что бы один using в середине кода не влиял на далнейшую функциональность всего дерева?) Так?

Comment: @BadCats: Ага, именно так. Либо using в середине будет влиять на начало, и тогда читая файл сверху будет непонятно, что означает что. Либо using в середине влияет только на остаток текста, и тогда один и тот же текст сверху и снизу будет означать разные вещи.

Answer (score 1):

Пространства имен сделаны не для компилятора, а для вас. Для того, чтобы не было пересечений одинаковых названий методов из разных пространств и вам не требовалось указывать весь длинный путь к нужному методу.

Для однозначности.

В примере кода (во второй части) вы хотите объявить пространство имен Namespaces перед Main. 
По логике создателей C# (как и остальных языков семейств C/Java) оптимальнее считается выносить каждый класс в отдельный файл. Допускается даже делить один класс между несколькими файлами.

А если вам в середине какого-то класса надо поработать с другим Namespace вы можете использовать using